# Unable to upload files to Drupal 7.5

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, cpanel

I have a Drupal 7.53 installed on CentOS6.8. After a year or so of working, I suddenly cannot upload files. So when creating a new node with no file upload, everything works fine. When I add a file, it fails, either showing "The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition." 500 error, or a Javascript Alert box with the same info.

The `tmp` folder has permissions 777, and the `sites/default/files` folder has permissions of 775.

Any ideas what went wrong??

-- UPDATE --
It may also be useful to know that the system is running under CPanel. So `httpd` runs as user "nobody".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First , check your files configuration in D7 admin .

Next , check if folder `sites/default/files` have recursively rights 777 and apache (or nginx) user has owner (something like `www-data`)

Finally, check your access logs if something wrong can be logged and run update.php to get some else information

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've checked the settings and permissions, they all as you say they should be. Update.php says there are no pending updates. Any other idea?

Comment: With cPanel  i think all files folder tree must be into 777 , also httpd can't write if is anonymous user

Comment: Thanks. I had support fix this for me. They mentioned it had "something to do with /tmp", but declined to say what it was.

Comment: maybe change destination for tmp , crete a tmp folder into files , and in drupal admin change to this new path tmp path settings and see if it's change something